# How do I make this enemy objective go more fastly when time passes

Tags: unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed = 0.5f;
    

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {

    }

    void MoveControl()
    {
        float yMove = moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.Translate(0, -yMove, 0);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        MoveControl();
       
    }

}
```

Comment: Please add more detail and context to your question
And exactly what it is you want to accomplish

Answer (score 1):

Declare a new variable for your acceleration amount:

```
public float acceleration = 1.0f;
```

in your MoveControl method:

```
void MoveControl()
{
    float yMove = moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    transform.Translate(0, -yMove, 0);
    moveSpeed += (acceleration * Time.deltaTime);
}
```